# c# Media player метод begin не выводит плеер из состояния Stopped

Tags: c#, wpf

В MSDN русским языком написано "Объект часов в состоянии Stopped может быть перезапущен с использованием метода Begin, Seek или SeekAlignedToLastTick.". Но как вы, наверное уже могли догадаться, плеер этого не делает. Ни при каких условиях. Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой, сможете подсказать что-нибудь.
На форме только 2 кнопки - play и pause соответственно.

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    MediaPlayer _player = new MediaPlayer();
    MediaTimeline _line = new MediaTimeline();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _line = new MediaTimeline(new Uri("http://online-hitfm.tavrmedia.ua/HitFM/"));
        _player.Clock = _line.CreateClock(true) as MediaClock;
    }

    private void play_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _player.Clock.Controller.Begin();
    }

    private void stop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _player.Clock.Controller.Stop();
    }
}
```

}

```
<Window x:Class="TestBeginMethod.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="play" Content="play" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="134,173,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="play_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="stop" Content="pause" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="350,173,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="stop_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: А ошибки какие-нибудь выводит? В других методах что делаете? (если код `WpfApplication` небольшой можно попробовать его весь выложить)....и `MainWindow.xaml`... в `play_Click` вообще попадаете?

Comment: В <play_Click> попадаю однозначно, а так же именно код в условии    _player.Clock.CurrentState == ClockState.Stopped тоже выполняется, но именно Begin не выводит из Stopped, даже в отдельном новом приложении из 2 кнопок.

Comment: думаю стоит все же показать немного больше кода, чтобы знать какие переменные юзаете, как создаете плеер и таймлайн, как связваете и где запускаете. Потому, что с предоставленными данными ничего не понятно и проблема не воспроиводится. Значит надо копать глубже

Comment: Написал абсолютно пустой проект, в котором тоже не работает Begin.

Comment: Я все понимаю. Но что-то там, в этом новом проекте, еще вы пишите? правда? при создании плеера, при инициализации `clock`, при отображении и т.д. может там ошибка изначально. И поэтому не работает. Поэтому я говорю что лучше показать что вы там пишите...... Или думаете что там всё идеально?

Comment: `MainWindow.xaml.cs`  и на всякий `MainWindow.xaml`

Comment: В изначальный пост добавил и разметку и код.

Comment: Становится яснее..... Думаю дело в том, что вы пытаетесь радио слушать...... с радио скорее всего надо работать через обычный `play/pause/stop`, т.е. как пример `_player.Open(new Uri("http://online-rusradio.tavrmedia.ua/RusRadio"));
            _player.Play();`  .... а через `timeline` и `clock` с конкретными композициями, а ля `http://muz-tv.ru/audio/f/c/fc8a796b75c753d4812763ac191a5965.mp3`  можете сами попробовать - вот список станций. http://vk.com/topic-38812004_26403188  и посмотреть что через стандартный play будет работать.